# Why in "Configure Data Source" when i choose "Parameter source :Control" all ControlIDs are duplicated?

Tags: asp.net, datasource, objectdatasource, configure

I don't know it happen  just to me or Others have the same situation too .

All the time when i bind a DataControl to an ObjectDataSource in "Configure Data Source" wizard of ObjectDataSource,when i set parameter source as "Control" in "ControlId" DropdownList there are **TWO** Item of every control in the WebForm , while it make sense be **one** .
[Configure Data Source http://sites.google.com/site/dindarbiz/_/rsrc/1262726225583/file-cabinet/ObjectDataSource.jpg](http://sites.google.com/site/dindarbiz/_/rsrc/1262726225583/file-cabinet/ObjectDataSource.jpg)

Comment: Did you figure out why this is happenning? I too have this same issue only on pages that use a master page. The work around is to click on the "Show advanced properties" link on the "Define Parameters". But it sure would be nice to figure out how I can keep the duplicate entries from displaying under ControlID in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found out it happen only when i use Master page , But i don't know why .